# load a word document inside window browser

Tags: .net, internet-explorer, download, ms-word

I have a page that dynamically links to a document that opens in a new page (the document is stored in a database as binary data and I loaded using the following code:

```
Response.ClearContent()
Response.ContentType = myReader("MIMEType").ToString()
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=" & myReader("Filename"))
Response.BinaryWrite(myReader("DocBD"))
Response.End()
```

This works ok. However some documents have restricted access and before loading the document the user is redirected to a login page. After entering username and passowrd the document is loaded. If it is a pdf file for example, it loads in the same login page, but when it is a word or excel document it opens outside the browser window and the login page remains in the background. Is ther a way to force a word or excel document to open inside the browser window?

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be no, due to the way Word works. Every document (and I think it consider the login as such) is opened in a different window.

Answer (score 0):

You will need a plugin that shows Word documents for the webbrowser.

The PDF reader you are using (Acrobat?) has a browser plugin, its not the browser that renders the content.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. How could you force the login page to close?

Comment: You can't. Once the document is downloaded it out of your reach

Comment: So do I have to leave the login page running (username and password still in the textboxes)? Nothing can be done? Thanks!

Comment: You could redirect after login. (response.redirect) and on the upload.aspx (for example) page you write your response.write code.

Comment: Hi, if I add a response.redirect line after Response.BinaryWrite, the page gets redirectered but the document doesn't load.